# How can I clear active NFS client-side server/volume entries that have become disassociated with any mounted filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, nfs, nfsv4

I have a situation where server-side mountpoints sometimes don't show up over NFS with a certain glitchy server. Typically restarting `nfsd` and/or fiddling with `/etc/exports` fixes things, but today this technique made everything worse: the client got into a state where it has an active (stuck?) connection to the NFS server in the kernel, but no mounts.

I think the active connection is keeping the broken server view in the client's memory. I want to completely disconnect the client so I can remount from scratch.

Here's the client's view of the server right now:

```
# cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/servers 
NV SERVER   PORT USE HOSTNAME
v4 c0a80002  801   1 192.168.0.2

# cat /proc/fs/nfsfs/volumes 
NV SERVER   PORT DEV          FSID                              FSC
v4 c0a80002  801 0:24         440f01c0e0f340b5:b7d3a2c45abef647 no
```

In the interests of completeness, the following is unredacted:

```
# cat /proc/mounts 
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=1028128k,nr_inodes=217391,mode=755 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup rw,relatime,cpuset,cpu,cpuacct,blkio,memory,devices,freezer,net_cls,perf_event,net_prio,pids 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
```

So there you go: an NFS connection, without any mounts.

#### My question:

**I want to run a nuclear steam roller over the client's NFS configuration so I can start again — but without rebooting. What can I do?**

Comment: I'd like to argue that my question *may* not be a duplicate, because the other question does not list `servers` and `volumes` in `/proc/fs/nfsfs`, and because only the output of `mount` was listed, not `/proc/mounts`. Unfortunately I can only say *may* because I gave up and rebooted the client, and cannot try the comment sequence in one of the answers.

Comment: The question can be re-opened, should you face the issue again and [edit] the question. It would be useful if you include details about mount options used, other attempts to solve the issue, or why the other question is not applicable.